# Flask Syntax Error

Tags: python, flask

I cant for the life of me figure out what is causing this syntax error, ive been looking at my code up and down and I cant figure it out because it was working just fine awhile ago. all it says is line 156 (the second to last one with the if **name** == "**main**":
    app.run)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sqlite3 as sql
import sqlite3

DATABASE = 'database.db'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.run(debug=True)

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config[DATABASE])

@app.route('/')
def index():

    con = sqlite3.connect("database.db") 
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from products")   
    rows = cur.fetchall();     

    return render_template('Index.html', rows=rows)

@app.route('/Purchase')
def Product_9():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            name = request.form['name']
            address = request.form['address']
            creditcard = request.form['creditcard']
            seccode = request.form['seccode']
            quantity = request.form['quantity']

            with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO purchase (name,addr,city,pin) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",(name,address,creditcard,seccode,quantity) )

                con.commit()
                msg = "Record successfully added"

            return render_template('Purchase.html', rows=rows)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: `run` is a function - use `app.run()` instead.

Comment: Thats not it, it still says theres a syntax error. on line 156

Comment: Then please edit your question with the  `Traceback` And which is line no 156 ?

Answer (score 1):

When the error is not in the line, it must be caused by something before it.

In this case, the error is `IndentationError: unexpected unindent`, because you have `try:` without `except` or `finally`.